# How to Access the private member of class?

Tags: php, oop

```
xPostModel Object
(
[script:Model:private] => abc
)
```

I wanna change abc to efg how can i do it ? Is there any way ?

Comment: Where do you need to change it? You can change it directly only in the class itself so if you need to change it outside of the class you would need to make a setter method for it in the class.

Comment: actually i dont have access .. i can only make object of it..

Comment: You could also use Reflection for this, but this should not be considered a good practise in normal situations. You can see an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6448613/1362634

Comment: not helpful in my case

Comment: Why is it not helpful for your case? It seems that you have a private class property $script which is inherited from parent class Model. I am trying to make an example using Reflection that would work in this situation. I've not used Reflection before myself so I'm not 100% sure it is possible in this inherited private property case.

Comment: I edited my answer below to show a working example of using Reflection to edit your object.

Comment: The marked "duplicate" does NOT answer this question. The duplicate question's answer does not even mention Reflection which is the only way to solve the problem that is asked here (see my answer). And there is no mention of PHP arrays here unlike on the duplicate.

Comment: Actually am using two php jabber frameworks .. each framework internally set the value of prefix of table but i wanna use model of one into another ..

Comment: @deceze NOT a duplicate, please reopen. See my previous comment.

Comment: So do you need to read a private property from another object first or what? Please explain your case in more detail (preferably with example code you are using) if you need more help. My answer below answers your original question.

Comment: Not only read I also want to write on it ..

Comment: I already gave you an example of how to write. Did you even read my answer below? It should not be too difficult to also figure out how to do the reading using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make changes to the class definition and there is no public setter method for the class property, and you really need to be able to directly edit the property outside the class, your only option is probably using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php) methods, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448613/1362634

Here is an example that should work in your case to set the private property `$script` in `$obj` of type `xPostModel` (where property is inherited from parent class `Model`):

```
$obj = new xPostModel();
$refProperty = new ReflectionProperty('Model', 'script');
$refProperty->setAccessible(true);
$refProperty->setValue($obj, 'def');
```

And here is a fully working code example with mockup class definitions to simulate the situation of the question.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Model {
    private $script = 'abc';
}

class xPostModel extends Model {}

$obj = new xPostModel();

print_r($obj); // Check original value of inherited private property

$refProperty = new ReflectionProperty('Model', 'script');
$refProperty->setAccessible(true);
$refProperty->setValue($obj, 'def');

print_r($obj); // Check that property has been changed
```