# How do I set visibility of members when they are dynamically assigned?

Tags: php, member

Let's say, we have a class like this:

```
class X {
    public static function create ($a, $b) {
        $x = new X();
        $x->$a = $b;
        return $x;
    }
}
```

`create()` assigns a member dynamically. However, this member is public:

```
>>> X::create("name", "Robert")
=> X {#93
     +"name": "Robert",
   }
>>> $x->name
=> "Robert"
```

Is there a way to make this member have protected or private visibility?

*(In my use case, members are specified later as in the above case, so, declaring `protected $some_var;` at the top won't help.)*

Comment: You can't. Explaining why you'd want to (I.e. what you are doing, not how you have tried to solve the problem) would probably point at a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way. See related question here: [Is there any way to set a private/protected static property using reflection classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448551/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-private-protected-static-property-using-reflection-cla)

The only possible thing is the other way - making a private member public.

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve as this is totally bad practice, but you could go with arrays:

```
<?php

class Foo
{

    private $data;

    function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }

        return null;
    }

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->var = 123;
var_dump($foo->var);
var_dump($foo);
```

Which will output like:

```
int(123)
object(Foo)#1 (1) {
["data":"Foo":private]=>
  array(1) {
        ["var"]=>
    int(123)
  }
}
```

So you can dynamically add properties to the class. The "properties" values are then stored in the array, which itself is private. The magic functions __get and __set are called if an not-existent (or private) property is access from outside. Then they handle the retrieving and setting of the values.

See doc on php.net here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php